# Speeding up quotient determination in high-radix montgomery modular multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic, montgomery-multiplication

In this paper [Simplifying Quotient Determination in High-Radix Modular Multiplication](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith12/papers/ARITH12_Orup.pdf), the authors have proposed to replace the original modulus $M$ in Montgomery Multiplication $ABR^{-1} \bmod{M}$ to a new value $\tilde{M} = (M' \bmod{2^k}) M$, where $(-MM')\bmod{2^k}=1$.

The new modulus $\tilde{M}$ is used to improve the original Montgomery multiplication algorithm but also gives an output in the range of $[0, 2\tilde{M})$ instead of the range $[0, 2M)$ I actually need. However, the paper does not mention how to convert the result back to the desired range. What should I do to retrieve the actual result of $ABR^{-1} \bmod{M}$?

Comment: taking $\mod M$ doesn't enough?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: could you write an answer so that we can close this?